# Delete specific cookie when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a drop down which is setting a cookie based on the users selection, this is doing a post back and the setting the cookie at this point. To give you a little more context the website is a catalog, the user goes and puts in their selection and then they search. At the top of the products shown there is a way to sort the list, this is where the cookie is set. This works well for normal situations until the customer does a new search or resets the search. because the sort has a cookie which is not tied directly to the search the cookie is maintained and always shows what was selected, even though now may not be sorting by this method after the new search has been done.

So I am seeking help on how I can delete this cookie set on the selection of a button, this button is:

```
  <a id="dnn_ctr555_ProductSearch_rpData_cmdAdvSearch_0" class="postbacklink searchpostbacklink nb-catfilter-search" href="javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$ctr555$ProductSearch$rpData$ctl00$cmdAdvSearch','')">Search</a>
```

to give you the details of the cookie and workings of the drop down see below:

```
 <!-- List header -->
 <select id="Selection" class="sorter" onchange="document.cookie= 'myDDIdx = ' + this.selectedIndex + '; path=/;';location=this.options[[this.selectedIndex]].value" style="float:right;margin-right:8px;">
  <option value="">Sort by</option>
  <option value="?orderby=0">Code</option>
  <option value="?orderby=1">Title A-Z</option>
  <option value="?orderby=2">Title Z-A</option>
  <option value="?orderby=3">Brand</option>
  <option value="?orderby=4">Lowest price</option>
  <option value="?orderby=5">Highest price</option>
  <option value="?orderby=6">Lowest Quantity</option>
  <option value="?orderby=7">Highest Quantity</option>
  </select>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>


  <script>
      var sidx = document.cookie.indexOf("myDDIdx");
       if(sidx != -1)
      window.onload = function () { document.getElementById("Selection").selectedIndex =                     document.cookie.substr(sidx + 8,1); }
  </script>
```

Any code snipits would be hugely appreciated, as I feel like I am smashing my head against a brick wall.

Comment: `document.cookie = 'myDDIdx=';` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

The original `document.cookie` API sucks. Instead of trying to access it directly, you should add this snippet:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#A_little_framework.3A_a_complete_cookies_reader.2Fwriter_with_full_unicode_support

```
var docCookies = {
  getItem: function (sKey) {
    return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
  },
  setItem: function (sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
    if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(sKey)) { return false; }
    var sExpires = "";
    if (vEnd) {
      switch (vEnd.constructor) {
        case Number:
          sExpires = vEnd === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case String:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case Date:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toUTCString();
          break;
      }
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
    return true;
  },
  removeItem: function (sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
    if (!sKey || !this.hasItem(sKey)) { return false; }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + ( sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + ( sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
    return true;
  },
  hasItem: function (sKey) {
    return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
  },
  keys: /* optional method: you can safely remove it! */ function () {
    var aKeys = document.cookie.replace(/((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, "").split(/\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/);
    for (var nIdx = 0; nIdx < aKeys.length; nIdx++) { aKeys[nIdx] = decodeURIComponent(aKeys[nIdx]); }
    return aKeys;
  }
};
```

Then you can simply execute this when the button is clicked:

```
docCookies.removeItem("myDDIdx");
```

Also, you can simplify the original cookie setter code to something like this:

```
<select id="Selection" class="sorter" onchange="docCookies.setItem('myDDIdx', this.selectedIndex); location=$(this).val();" style="float:right;margin-right:8px;">
```

(Not sure what the reason is for setting the location variable, though I've simplified it assuming you have jQuery loaded, since your question was tagged with jQuery)

Comment: So I have tried the above and it is setting the cookie but is not setting the location, so on a refresh the drop down selection is lost

Comment: Was it setting it before? What is the `location` variable used for? Your code doesn't show where it's used. Refreshing a page will always clear all the javascript variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the cookie names with you then pure javascript:

```
        var Cookienames = ['cookie1', 'cookie2', 'cookie3'];
            function clearCookies(Cookienames){
                for(i=0; i <= Cookienames.length; i++){
                    document.cookie = Cookienames[i] + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';  
                }
            }
```

Call this function where you want to delete the cookies. clearCookies(Cookienames);

Also, if you are setting the cross browser cookie with parent domain then:

```
 function clearCookies(Cookienames){
                for(i=0; i <= Cookienames.length; i++){
                    document.cookie = Cookienames[i] + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;domain=".xyz.com";path=/';  
                }
            }
```